# Relevance of this equation

Tags: energy, variational-principle

The book 'The variational princples of mechanics' by Lanczos was recommended to me and I am reading it now. So far it is an enjoyable journey, but I don't see the significance of this equation:

$t = \int \frac{dq}{\phi(E,q)} + \tau \;(53.19)$

which is derived from the energy theorem (which I believe is):

$\sum^n_{i =1} p_i \dot q_i - L = const \; (53.12)$

by rewriting it to:

$f(q,\dot q) = E \; (53.17)$

$\dot q = \phi(E,q)\; (53.18)$

Now I don't see why it would be relevant to express the independent variable $t$ as function of state variables. Especially if simple mass-spring system is inserted into this equation, giving $t$ as a root of the other state variables.

Can someone tell my why this is relevant, or if I am doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation (53.13) gives a formula for the lapsed time $\Delta T$ as the function of the [mechanical energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_energy) $E$. This is useful in many physical situations. As a variational problem of minimizing $\Delta T$, see e.g. the [Brachistochrone problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html).